# How to configure Lighthttpd with fastcgi

Tags: c++, fastcgi, lighttpd

I've installed LightTPD on windows.
It starts without fastcgi normally.
Then I copy/paste one of the fastCGI examples

```
#include <sstream>  // manipulate strings (integer conversion)
#include <string>   // work with strings in a more intuitive way
#include "libfcgi2.h" // Header file for libfcgi2.dll (linked with libfcgi2.lib)

using namespace std;

int main( )
{ 
    printf("Start...\r\n");
    FCGX_REQUEST Req = { 0 }; // Create & Initialize all members to zero
    int count(0);
    string sReply;
    ostringstream ss;

    FCGX_InitRequest( &Req, 0, 0 ); // FCGX_DEBUG - third parameter

    // Open Database
    while(true)
    {
        if( FCGX_Accept_r(&Req) < 0 ) break; // Execution is blocked here until a Request is received
        count++; 
        ss << count; // Stringstream is a typesafe Integer conversion
        sReply = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n   Hello World " + ss.str();
        FCGX_PutStr( sReply.data(),   sReply.length(),   Req.pOut ); 
        ss.str(""); // clear the string stream object
    }

    // Close Database
    printf("End...\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and trying to start server with following config:

```
server.modules              = (
    ...
    "mod_fastcgi",

....

fastcgi.server = ( ".exe" =>
    ( "" =>
        ( "bin-path" => "C:\FastCGI\Examples\C++\Ex_Counter.exe",
           "port" => 8080,
           "min-procs" => 1,
           "max-procs" => 1
        )
    )
)
```

And gain error on start up:

```
C:\LightTPD>LightTPD.exe -f conf\lighttpd-inc.conf -m lib -D
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: conf\lighttpd-inc.conf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: conf/lighttpd-inc.conf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (log.c.166) server started
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1367) --- fastcgi spawning local
        proc: C:\FastCGI\Examples\C++\Ex_Counter.exe
        port: 8080
        socket
        max-procs: 1
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1391) --- fastcgi spawning
        port: 8080
        socket
        current: 0 / 1
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1104) the fastcgi-backend C:\FastCGI\Example
s\C++\Ex_Counter.exe failed to start:
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1108) child exited with status 0 C:\FastCGI\
Examples\C++\Ex_Counter.exe
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1111) If you're trying to run your app as a
FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (mod_fastcgi.c.1399) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
2011-10-07 12:50:25: (server.c.942) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

I'm not using php, so i don't know where i should set this flag.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the example failed to call FCGX_Init() before it started using the FCGX library functions.  This will cause FCGX_Accept_r to return a non 0 error condition and causes your example to exit with the 0 status indicated in the log file you are seeing.

From [fcgiapp.h](http://www.fastcgi.com/cvs/fcgi2/include/fcgiapp.h):

```
/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * FCGX_Accept_r --
 *
 *      Accept a new request (multi-thread safe).  Be sure to call
 *  FCGX_Init() first.
 *
```

Comment: But there is no FCGX_Init() in libfcgi2.h

Comment: @Ivan, hmm I see. Are you using a spin off of that source from www.coastrd.com?  If you look in their libfcgi2.h file you will see a very similar comment that says FCXG_Init() must be called first.  Since they don't have that function declared I suspect there is a subtle bug or some kind of other prerequisite they hadn't updated the example for.  I would contact them directly about the example.

The main source base for fastcgi2 I know of is at http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5 and I think is where that company migrated their version from.

Comment: Try to use another library, from http://www.fastcgi.com/dist/fcgi.tar.gz
Downloaded, unpacked it, biult from "Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)"
nmake -f Makefile.nt

Copy fcgi-2.4.0\libfcgi\Release\libfcgi.dll to fcgi-2.4.0\examples\echo-cpp\Release\libfcgi.dll

And use lightttpd config with:
"bin-path" => "C:\Downloads\fcgi-2.4.0\examples\echo-cpp\Release\echo-cpp.exe"

Comment: C:\LightTPD>LightTPD.exe -f conf\lighttpd-inc.conf -m lib -D
...
2011-10-27 10:45:46: (mod_fastcgi.c.1391) --- fastcgi spawning
        port: 9000
        socket
        current: 0 / 1
unknown listenType (0)
2011-10-27 10:45:46: (mod_fastcgi.c.1104) the fastcgi-backend C:\Downloads\fcgi-
2.4.0\examples\echo-cpp\Release\echo-cpp.exe failed to start:
....

error unknown listenType (0) occured at http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/echo-cpp.cpp::113

while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)